# Export Member requests for a facebook group?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to go through a new facebook group's member requests and am hoping for a better way.  One of the requirements of joining the group is for the potential member to sign up for a service provided by the company hosting the group.

I'd like to be able to just export the "Member Requests" section as a CSV and compare it to the list of people that have signed up for the service, then automatically approve those people.

Is there an existing tool that does this or am I going to have to hack together a screen scraper to do this for me?